# Jasmine Karma Test injected $q is undefined

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

This is something I've done 100 times, but for the life of me cannot work out what is happening here.

I've have this existing test module where all 20+ tests were working perfectly.

Now I'm trying to add `$q` to this service for a new method.  I'm using the exact same method I've used previously, but for some reason `$q` is undefined:

```
describe( 'CacheService module', () => {
  let cacheService, $q, $scope;

  beforeEach( () => {
    angular.mock.module( 'app.CacheService', ( $provide ) => {
      $provide.value( '$q', $q );
    });

    inject( ( _$rootScope_, _$q_, _CacheService_ ) => {
      $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
      $q = _$q_;

      cacheService = _CacheService_;

      console.log( _$q_ ); // undefined
    });
  });
});
```

Service under test declared as:

```
angular.module('app.CacheService', [] ).service( 'CacheService', [ '$q', function( $q ) {
    ....
}]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you providing a value for $q in your module definition? The value you are $provide as $q is undefined and is therefore undefined when you are in your inject block. Your code should look like this:

```
describe( 'CacheService module', () => {
  let cacheService, $q, $scope;

  beforeEach( () => {
    //angular.mock.module( 'app.CacheService', ( $provide ) => {
    //  $provide.value( '$q', $q );
    //});
    // Do not provide a custom value for $q that is undefined
    angular.mock.module( 'app.CacheService');

    // Now $q will come from angular instead of your provided value,
    // which was undefined since you never set it.
    inject( ( _$rootScope_, _$q_, _CacheService_ ) => {
      $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
      $q = _$q_;

      cacheService = _CacheService_;

      console.log( _$q_ ); // Should now be defined...
    });
  });
});
```

Specifically, you might use a function with $provide in a test when you want to override an existing definition. For example, if you are testing a controller that depends on a service that uses $http, maybe you just want to create stubs for all those methods in your service (with a spy for instance).

Comment: Ah! You're right! I'm actually injecting another mocked service in my actual code, so I still need that provide block, but removing `$provide.value( '$q', $q )` from it has fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: I just took it out because in your example you weren't setting anything else in there. Definitely need it if you are providing mocks. Glad it's working now.